# How to install Windows XP printer driver on Windows 7 prof x64?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, 64-bit, printer

Windows 7 has a feature to store printer drivers on the same computer where printer is located. When user on client computer tries to open it, windows automatically downloads driver and installs it.

I have Windows 7 x64 with Epson AL-C1100 connected to it. There are no Epson drivers for Windows 7 for this printer, but during system installation Windows installed some Microsoft drivers.

Now I wish to share this printer for Windows XP notebook.

When I am trying to open the printer from XP, I see that there is no appropriate driver on Win7. So, I am trying to install it.

When I am pressing addition drivers button in printer properties dialog, I see a list of processor architectures. x64 is selected, Itanium and x86 are not. If I am trying to select x86, it asks for disk location. Epson drivers for this printer for windows XP do not match.

What does it want?

---

How can my 2012 year question be "duplicate" of 2013 one???

Comment: I've run into this problem with no clear solution. The workaround for me on an HP printer was to find drivers for a _different_ printer that worked on both XP and Seven, but still understood my printer.

Comment: Why not install the XP drivers for the epson on the XP notebook?

Comment: Yes I did so; but the question is what windows is asking for and how to give her existing drivers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install 32 bit driver in XP mode on my Windows 7 64-bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/611299/can-i-install-32-bit-driver-in-xp-mode-on-my-windows-7-64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Run the following:
Start > Run > printmanagement.msc

Use this interface to set it up. This lets you separate all the steps, making it smoother and letting you know exactly where the issue is. First go down to servers, your PC, drivers, and add the drives themselves as an available package. You may also need to toy with the Isolation settings (accessible by right clicking the package after you add it).

Once you have the drivers loaded, then assign them to the printer. Under the printer properties sharing tab additional drivers they should now be available. The server version gives you more flexibility, but you can generally jam drivers into the desktop version with enough effort.