# Can I install 32 bit driver in XP mode on my Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, drivers, 64-bit

I need to install 32 bit driver on my Windows 7 64-bit operating system. I have got a reply from the vendor saying it's not supported on 64-bit OS. Is it possible to run the driver inside virtual machine. Since Microsoft provides free XP mode, I can try that. Let me know if you has tried this or there is a workaround to install the driver. I really need to install the driver. Changing the computer is not an option.

Target board I'm using has ARM9 and its proprietary. There is no other source to find the driver.

I'm using NP550P5C 15.6" Series 5 Notebook. Spec: Intel i7(3rd gen), 8GB RAM

Comment: What kind of driver are we talking about?

Comment: as david said, what driver you want to install? and isn't there a 64 bit version of the driver? and what pc do you have? maybe we can find the right driver for you. For example i didn't find all the driver that i want from the hp site, but i found them elsewhere

Comment: @abhishek It depends on what kind of device it is.  Even if it does work the device would only be visible to the guest os not the host os.  All Windows 7 licenses support be installed as either x86 or x64.  So the reinstallation of the operating is an option you should consider.

Comment: I want to install driver for target board which has ARM9 processor. It is a proprietary board. Vendor has mentioned they don't support 64 bit OS. Sadly changing the OS is not an option. My system admin is not so lenient.

Comment: I'm using NP550P5C 15.6" Series 5 Notebook. It has 8GB RAM.

Comment: Fill in the blank: The device connects to the computer using a _BLANK_. Generally USB and serial devices are supported (passed thorugh to the XP Mode environment) which then lets you install drivers and/or software in XP Mode to make use of the device there and not in the host Windows 7 OS.

Comment: The device connects to the computer using a **USB**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XP mode allowed me to install the 32 bit driver. I was working with [DNW](https://code.google.com/p/dnw/). I had to attach the USB manually. Answer for this question is "Yes, it works sometimes"

But USB connection with DNW on a 64 bit Windows 7 didn't work correctly. If you have come here searching for installing USB driver for DNW under Windows 7 64-bit, you are out of luck. I found a similar question here: http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/261

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly install it in XP Mode, but since that's just Windows XP in a Virtual PC VM, it will not magically become available to Windows 7. You need a 64-bit Windows 7 driver or different equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the 32-bit drivers on a 64 bit system:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup
DisableDecoratedModelsRequirement 1 DWORD
```

Install driver in `Device Manager` as update driver manual.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the executable for the driver (if it has an installer) in compatibility mode (Windows XP SP3).

Comment: It is a .sys file. Windows doesn't provide an option to run in compatibility mode. Even if it does, it doesn't provide option to run in 32-bit mode.